# SharePoint REST API & CAML query integration Online Add in/App

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, caml, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to integrate CAML query in rest API and trying to get data from a SharePoint List residing in host web.
I am using method:

```
function getDataWithCaml(listName, caml) {
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWeb);
    var endpoint = appWeb + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('"
        + listName + "')/items?@target='" + siteUrl + "'";
    var requestData = {
        "query":
               {
                   "__metadata":
                     { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }
                  , "ViewXml": caml
               }
    };
    return executor.executeAsync({
        url: endpoint,
        method: "POST",
        data: requestData,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
    });
}
```

And the caml is simple as this:

```
var caml = "<View><Query><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Test</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Test</Value></Eq></Or></Where></Query></View>";
```

I am getting error as:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (FORBIDDEN)

I have given permission to the list as well as the web with full control.

Just want to know why is it coming up with this error.

I have tried changing the endpoint URL to `siteUrl + "/_api//web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items` where siteUrl is host web URL.

Any help is appreciated.